# react-bootstrap <Row><Col lg='3'></Col></Row> remove default padding - React JS

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

In a react app I want to remove padding from both left and right sides of each column. I guess this padding of 15px is being given to each column by react-bootstrap because what I saw is as:

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

which is not removable(I tried to do so but failed). My images on a page are showing as below:

[image]

**Note:** showing color **Green** is padding from both left and right side applied to each column which I want to remove.

My desired output for images on a page is something like as below:

[image]

My code:

.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import './style.scss';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Images } from '../../../../Shared/Assets';
import ImagesIcon from '../../../../Components/Cells/ImagesIcon'

const ImgGallery = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className='ImgGalry'>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg='3'>
                        <ImagesIcon src={Images.xgallery4} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col lg='3'>
                        <ImagesIcon src={Images.xgallery2} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col lg='3'>
                        <ImagesIcon src={Images.xgallery1} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col lg='3'>
                        <ImagesIcon src={Images.xgallery2} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default ImgGallery;
```

.scss file

```
.ImgGalry{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #01FF56;
   img{
       width: 100% !important;
       height: 100% !important;
   }
}
```

To all, is it possible to remove or hide padding of column(s) when created using react-bootstrap? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add px-0 class to col

```
       <Row className="no-gutters">
            <Col lg='3' className="px-0">
                <ImagesIcon src={Images.xgallery4} />
            </Col>
            <Col lg='3' className="px-0">
                <ImagesIcon src={Images.xgallery2} />
            </Col>
            <Col lg='3' className="px-0">
                <ImagesIcon src={Images.xgallery1} />
            </Col>
            <Col lg='3' className="px-0">
                <ImagesIcon src={Images.xgallery2} />
            </Col>
        </Row>
```

Comment: Avani, one of my senior strictly told me not to use class with Col. He will refuse this approach. Isn't there any other way to set paddings to 0px. BTW, what class='px-0' will do?

Comment: px-0 will do padding-left = 0, padding-right = 0

Comment: bootstrap suggesting same thing.. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters

Comment: Avani, I got it. If I'm not wrong this x is correspond to y where both used for left, right, top and bottom.

Comment: please follow this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Avani, I'm not allowed to use specifier classes as a nested class.

Comment: Avani, By following https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters I did the same by my own. But now they want me to get this done using react-bootstrap <Row><Col>

Comment: make sure you have added no-gutters class to row and px-0 class to col

Comment: Avani, Are you suggesting me try something like <Row class='no-gutters'> <Col lg='3' class='px-0'></Col></Row>?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234618/discussion-between-avani-bataviya-and-sololearner).